# Question about random sample vs support

Tags: random-variable

I got a quick question.
Say you have X is random variable X=1 you have sucess X=0 you have failure.
And you the following list of number
[1,0,0,0,1]
So would the list be the support of the random variable or would each item in the list be a random variable.
This got me confused.

Comment: This notion is a tricky one until you get it, but each item in the list is a realization of a random variable. Perhaps think of it this way: once you flip the coin and check which side is up, the situation is totally determined, but before then, you have a random variable of a coin flip.

Comment: I see because each random variable is a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A. Random experiment: flip a coin**

Sample space: $\Omega=\{H,T\}$
Event (result of the random experiment): $E=H$ (or $E=T$)
Random variable $X\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$: $H\mapsto 1, T\mapsto 0$
Support of the random variable (the set of its possible values): $\{0,1\}$
Realization of the random variable: $H\mapsto1\Rightarrow X=1$ (or $T\mapsto 0\Rightarrow X=0$)

**B. Random experiment: flip five coins**

Sample space: $\Omega=\{(H,H,H,H,H),(H,H,H,H,T),\dots,(T,T,T,T,T)\}$
Event (result of the random experiment): $E=(H,H,H,H,H)$ (or $E=(H,H,H,H,T)$, $\dots$, or $E=(T,T,T,T,T)$)
Random variable $X\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$: sum of $H\mapsto 1$, $T\mapsto 0$
Support of the random variable (a set of real numbers): $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$
Realization of the random variable: $(H,H,H,H,H)\mapsto(1,1,1,1,1)\Rightarrow X=5$ (or $4$, or $3$, or $2$, or $1$, or $0$ if $E\ne(H,H,H,H,H)$)